# IllegalStateException: Invalid tables when trying to query database with ContentProvider

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I am getting the below error when attempting to query my database with my custom `ContentProvider` shown below.

I have confirmed the table exists with the correct name and it is still not working.

I was able to get it to work with a raw query, but i want to us the `ContentProvider` pattern for practice.

Thanks, let me know if you need more information.

---

**SQLiteOpenHelper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String DB_PATH = 
            "/data/data/ashton.android.personal.worktc/databases/";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "worktc.db";

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = this.checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            //do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            Log.e(TAG, "Database does not exist when trying to create it.");

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();

            try {

                this.copyDataBase();

                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();

    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = this.context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        this.myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return this.myDatabase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(this.myDatabase != null)
            this.myDatabase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

---

**ContentProvider**

```
public class WorkTCContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final String TAG = WorkTCContentProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String AUTHORITY = 
            "ashton.android.personal.worktc.database";

    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(
                AUTHORITY, 
                ProfessionTable.TABLE_NAME, 
                ProfessionTable.PROFESSIONS);

        sURIMatcher.addURI(
                AUTHORITY, 
                ProfessionTable.TABLE_NAME + "/#", 
                ProfessionTable.PROFESSIONS_ID);
    }

    private DatabaseHelper database;

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        Log.d(TAG, "before database creation");

        this.database = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        try {
            this.database.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.database.openDataBase();
        this.database.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "after database creation");

//      this.database.getWritableDatabase().execSQL( "pragma foreign_keys = on;" );

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ProfessionTable.PROFESSIONS:

            /*
             * Dont do anything, just do the normal query.
             */

            break;

        case ProfessionTable.PROFESSIONS_ID:

            queryBuilder.appendWhere(ProfessionTable._ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());

            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(
                db, 
                projection, 
                selection, 
                selectionArgs, 
                null, 
                null, 
                sortOrder);

        cursor.setNotificationUri(WorkTCApp.getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

**ProfessionTable**

```
public final class ProfessionTable implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Professions";

    public static final Uri URI = 
            Uri.parse("content://" + WorkTCContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_NAME);

    public static final int PROFESSIONS = 10;

    public static final int PROFESSIONS_ID = 11;

    public static final String NAME = "name";

    public static final String ICON = "icon";

    private ProfessionTable() {}
}
```

---

**Error**

```
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ashton.android.personal.worktc/ashton.android.personal.worktc.controllers.WorkActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.findEditTable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1127)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:280)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at ashton.android.personal.worktc.database.worktcContentProvider.query(worktcContentProvider.java:104)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:187)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:267)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at ashton.android.personal.worktc.views.WorkView.onFinishInflate(WorkView.java:96)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:631)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:8884)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at ashton.android.personal.worktc.controllers.WorkActivity.onCreate(WorkActivity.java:30)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-08 11:16:18.285: E/AndroidRuntime(11651):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
```

I noticed that you don't call `setTables()`:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.setTables(ProfessionalTable.TABLE_NAME);
```

before attempting to run your query.

Comment: I am calling `SQLiteDatabase db = this.database.getReadableDatabase();` doesn't that open/create the database if needed? That is what it says in the javadoc.

Comment: `Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(`

Comment: Thanks, your edit solved my problem. Another set of eyes is wonderful. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final Uri URI = Uri.parse(
        "content://" + WorkTCContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_NAME);
```

Please change the clause above to the clause below.  That is, change to a single `/` after`content:`

```
public static final Uri URI = Uri.parse(
        "content:/" + WorkTCContentProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_NAME);
```